# Prediction of solubility (from chemical structure) at different pHs

Tags: solubility, software

I would like to know What is the best method for predicting the water solubility (and in other solvents) of a compound given its molecular structure at different pHs. What I know now is based on the seminal paper from Eisenberg et al.;

```
Eisenberg, D. & McLachlan, A. D. Solvation energy in protein folding and binding. Nature 319, 199–203 (1986).
```

where partition coefficient can be estimated depending on each atom type and its exposed surface to the solvent (SASA). This seems to work well for many substances, but I have the problem that I need to know the solubility dependence of some substances against pH, and I the only thing I found now as [Chemaxon](http://www.chemaxon.com/products/marvin/) tools, but their results are not very accurate. It seems that the best option might be quantum mechanical calculations and tools such as [COSMO-RS](http://www.cosmologic.de/index.php). At the moment we can not pay its license.

So in summary, I wonder what approaches do you suggest for calculating solubility of small chemical compounds depending on pH. Any method/software/server would be fine for us.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. Please provide some examples, to show what effort has been put in the query by you.

Comment: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ci800058v Would be a good start for reading, but its paywalled.

Comment: I'll reopen this once you add some examples and shown us some of your own thought process on the matter (see the [faq] and [ask])

Comment: I'm reopening this for now. It's borderline "not constructive", however, since it asks for "the best" method (and is effectively a software recommendation). Please add your additional improvements from your other questions here as well.

Comment: sorry again, you can close or delete this and let open this one;  http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4251/prediction-of-solubility-from-chemical-structure-at-different-phs#comment6417_4251